# TinyMCE and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, laravel-views

I'm trying to use tinyMCE with my Laravel project. The problem is when I store the new article the html tags are not working. They're showing up like a plain text on display on my laravel view:

[image]

This is the code implemented in create.blade.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector : "textarea",
        plugins : ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor", "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen", "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"],
        toolbar : "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Markup is escaped by default in Laravel. Are you using `{!! $article->content !!}` instead of `{{ $article->content }}` to render your body?

Comment: {{$article->body}} I'm using it like this. But my form is written like this:
{!! Form::open() !!}

Comment: Glad it helped. Answer posted for future reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Markup is escaped by default in Laravel. If you're storing text in your database that contains markup, you will either want to apply a getter to your Eloquent Model that will unescape it for you, or use the following Blade syntax:

```
{!! $model->text !!}
```

When dealing with unescaped output, I would highly recommend limiting the tags that can be applied in your TinyMCE editor by using the [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements) attribute.