# pass tinymce textarea text with laravel 4.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-4.2

I have a form that has tinymce textarea to enable the user edit a text and save it in database with 'HTML tags' to display it in his profile, the problem is laravel 4.2 escape the HTML tags and can't read it in my controller

```
{{ Form::open(['class'=>'form-inline','id'=>'product_description_form']) }}
{{ Form::textarea('eng_desc', $eng_desc, ['id' => 'eng_desc']) }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="descripttion_save" ><?php echo trans('vo_labels.save'); ?></button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

{

```
  public function saveProductDescription() {
    $post_data = Input::all();
    print_r($post_data);die();
```

}
}

Comment: can you post printr data

Comment: Array
(
    [_token] => kmQMCDKMqriTbiSPuayXfV96KznpqTPDNW2Lg094
[eng_desc] => Explore a whole new world of traveling with LIVE TOURS Membership
)

Comment: eng_desc --> displayed as normal text without any html tags

Answer (score 0):

Laravel escape it by default, please refer to this similar post. Hope it helps
[TinyMCE and Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224938/tinymce-and-laravel)